# Distribution of $e^{\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i}$ with gaussian $Z$

Tags: probability

> a) If $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, find the distribution of $e^{\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i}$.

$X = \sum_{i=1}^N Z_i\sim N(n\mu,\sqrt{n}\sigma).$ But then what would the distribution of $e^X$ be?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad I showed the distribution of X in my steps? Then I was stuck on the exponential step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X=log Y$ follows a Gaussian distribution (which is exactly your case)...

then Y is  [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

PS:

- you supposed also that the N gaussian are independent (if they are not independent the distribution of $\sum_i Z_i$ is always a Gaussian but with different parameters
- you confused $n$ with $N$; it is not a big deal, perhaps only a typo